# Collection of ahadith arranged according to sahabi from whom the hadith is narrated

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, books, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

I once came across the name of a collection of ahadith which had ahadith ordered by the sahabi from whom the hadith was narrated, so that all the ahadith narrated from one sahabi were listed first, and then all from another sahabi and so on.
I can't seem to find it now.
Please tell me its name.

Answer (score 3):

About any hadith collection that has been entitled al-Musnad المسند or al-Mo'jam  المعجم meets the desired conditions.

As Musnad means a book arranged in chapters or sections that quote ahadith of the same Sahabi () with no special order.
And a Mo'jam is about the same but the arrangement is in an alphabetical order, but it must not necessary be for the sahabah (see the short overview on the three books of [at-Tabarani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tabarani)). The above distinction between al-Musnad and al-Mo'jam is based on [this fatwa](http://www.dr-shaal.com/fatwa/6804.html) -in Arabic- and the definition given in the Arabic Wikipedia site of Musnad Ahmad (see [here](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AF_%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF)).

> وأما المسانيد فإنها تمتاز بأن أصحابها جمعوا مسند كل صحابي على حدة من دون اعتبار لحال الحديث صحة وضعفاً ومن غير ترتيب موضوعي، كما عمل الإمام أحمد والحميدي.
> As for the Masaneed (plural of al-Musnad) their particularity is that the author have gathered all musnad (connected chains) of a Sahabi for it's own, without any care about the hadith's soundness or weaknesses, and without ordering them thematically, as did the imam's Ahamd and al-Hamidi.
>
> وأما المعاجم فإنها تمتاز بجمع المؤلفين أحاديث رووها حسب ترتيب الصحابة أو شيوخهم، حيث يأتي المؤلف بمرويات كل شيخ أو صحابي وحده من دون عناية بالموضوعات ولا اعتبار للصحة مثل ما عمل الطبراني في الأوسط، فقد جمعه حسب شيوخه، وفي الكبير فقد ذكر ما تيسر له عن كل صحابي.
> As for the Ma'ajim (plural of al-Mo'jam) their particularity is that the authors gathered ahadith based on the order of the sahabah or their teachers (Shoyokh), the author there in quotes all the narrations of a sahabi or sheikh not caring about their topics nor their soundess as did at-Tabarni in his al-Awsat, where he collected the narrations of his teachers, while in al-Kabeer he quoted what he had in hand of the narrations of the sahabah. (Source: Fatwa islamweb #[61637](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/61637))

This definition of al-Mo'jam seems to oppose the opinion of it referring to an alphabetical order. Imam at-Tabarani in his al-Mo'jam al-Kabir المعجم الكبير actually orderd the book as follows: Starting with the 4 rashidi caliphs, completing the ten who were promised paradise then he went forth by the other sahaba in an alphabetical order (if a sahabi was known to have narrated many ahadith he only quoted some of them else he would quote most or all of them). While in his al-Mo'jam al-Awsat المعجم الأوسط he quoted  narrations in the order of his teachers (Shoyokh) in alphabetical order. The difference between al-Mo'jam as-Saghir المعجم الصغير and al-'Awsat basically is that in as-Saghir he only quoted one or two narrations of his teachers, while in al-Awsat he quoted all of them. Note that imam at-Tabarani has arranged also some rather unknown Musnads: Musnad 'Aishah, Musnad abu Hurairah, Musnad abu Dharr etc.

The most prominent among the al-Musnads and maybe the largest one is certainly Musnad Ahmad of the imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal and it is arranged starting with the ahadith of the al-'Ashara al-Mubashara and ending with those of female Sahaba. Imam a-Shafi'i has also a compilation entitled Musnad a-Shafi'i and Abu Hanifa too.  And at-Tabarani's al-Mo'jam al-Kabir.

See also: [What was the earliest Hadith Book / Collection to be recorded?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35811/what-was-the-earliest-hadith-book-collection-to-be-recorded/35839#35839) where I've quoted from the introduction of Fath al-Barry a bit about the history of hadith compilation and about the earliest Musnad's and on a short overiview of the content of the three Mo'jams of at-Tabarani check [Did the Prophet say "lesbianism among women is zina between them"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/did-the-prophet-say-lesbianism-among-women-is-zina-between-them).

Answer (score 2):

The Musnad of Imam Ahmad Ibn Hanbal is organised like that, each sahabi has his own division and all hadith from one sahabi are together.